# Android - get facebook profile picture

Tags: android, facebook, profile

I don't know why, but I am always getting null when I try to get the profile picture of the user. Do I need to set some specific permissions to get access?

Below is my method:

```
public static Bitmap getFacebookProfilePicture(String userID) throws SocketException, SocketTimeoutException, MalformedURLException, IOException, Exception
{
   String imageURL;

   Bitmap bitmap = null;
   imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=large";
   InputStream in = (InputStream) new URL(imageURL).getContent();
   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

   return bitmap;
}

Bitmap bitmap = getFacebookProfilePicture(userId);
```

I am getting null. I don't know the reason why? Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Did you set the application hash in the facebook developer page? Do other facebook calls work? Did you check your log? You might have an incorrect hash (which happens pretty often).

Comment: @JeffreyKlardie you even don't need facebook api to get profile pics.

Comment: You're right. I was not aware of that. I added an answer that is slightly different; I use `URL.openConnection().getInputStream()` instead of `URL.getContent();`

Answer (score 75):

This should work:

```
public static Bitmap getFacebookProfilePicture(String userID){
    URL imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream());

    return bitmap;
}

Bitmap bitmap = getFacebookProfilePicture(userId);
```

### Edit:

As suggested by [@dvpublic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855072/android-get-facebook-profile-picture#comment34682218_19855492) in the comments, the problem of image not being downloaded is fixed using by "https" in favour of "http".

Comment: It seems to me that the last SDK did this method stops working. Anyone know what happened? BitmapFactory.decodeStream always returns null now

Comment: I suspect, that SDK is not blame and the problem is in redirection. Try to open link "http://graph.facebook.com/USER_UID/picture" in browser - the link "httpS://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/..." will be opened. Auto redirection works automatically when original and redirected protocols are same. So, try to load images from "httpS://graph.facebook.com/USER_UID/picture" and make sure, that HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true) or conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true) is called. Then BitmapFactory.decodeStream will work again.

Comment: getting Error > SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null

Answer (score 54):

use the facebook ProfilePictureView instead of an Imageview

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
    android:id="@+id/friendProfilePicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    facebook:preset_size="small"/>
```

After that you can set facebook id like this in code

```
ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;

profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.friendProfilePicture);

profilePictureView.setProfileId(userId);
```

it works..
also You can set the size to small/normal/large/custom for `ProfilePictureView`

Comment: how to make Circular ProfilePictureView.

Comment: then you need to make custom ProfilePictureView for that.                                                           


Reference Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464707/display-fb-profile-pic-in-circular-image-view-in-application

Comment: Oh Thanks man! You are a life saver. Struggling since an hour

Answer (score 29):

Simply use Picasso. Add Picasso Library and then use this simple line code:

```
userpicture = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.postuserid);

Picasso.with(context)
       .load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID+ "/picture?type=large")
       .into(userpicture);
```

Comment: if you use Picasso then it will load same image because of caching so when profile is changed you will not see updated image using Picasso.

Answer (score 18):

Best way to Get Profile Picture URL

```
int dimensionPixelSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(com.facebook.R.dimen.com_facebook_profilepictureview_preset_size_large);
Uri profilePictureUri= Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(dimensionPixelSize , dimensionPixelSize);
```

or

```
Uri profilePictureUri = ImageRequest.getProfilePictureUri(Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId(), dimensionPixelSize , dimensionPixelSize );
```

Use Glide to show Image

```
Glide.with(this).load(profilePictureUri)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(profilePictureView);
```

No more hard-coded string

Comment: there is also a built in function to get the profile image in the Profile object: Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri

Answer (score 15):

You have to call GraphRequest API for getting URL of current Profile Picture.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "id,email,picture.type(large)");
new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me", params, HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                        if (data.has("picture")) {
                            String profilePicUrl = data.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                            Bitmap profilePic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(profilePicUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
                            // set profilePic bitmap to imageview
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
}).executeAsync();
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Don't forget to make a new URL object from the `String url`: `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream());`

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE: From 26 Mar 2018, all solutions related to manual link don't work anymore**

You should follow the [official guide here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/)

```
private static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_PROFILE_IMAGE = "picture.type(large)";
    private static String FACEBOOK_FIELDS = "fields";

    private void getFacebookData() {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                (object, response) -> {
                    updateAvatar(getImageUrl(response));
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString(FACEBOOK_FIELDS, FACEBOOK_FIELD_PROFILE_IMAGE);
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    private static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_PICTURE = "picture";
    private static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_DATA = "data";
    private static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_URL = "url";
    private String getImageUrl(GraphResponse response) {
        String url = null;
        try {
            url = response.getJSONObject()
                    .getJSONObject(FACEBOOK_FIELD_PICTURE)
                    .getJSONObject(FACEBOOK_FIELD_DATA)
                    .getString(FACEBOOK_FIELD_URL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return url;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, was wondering why facebook profile pictures suddenly disappeared from apps....

Answer (score 4):

> check the user Id use this url

```
imgurl="https://graph.facebook.com/"+user.getId()+"/picture";
```

Answer (score 4):

I always received a response stating a `FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT`. So looking back in Facebook’s graph API explorer I noted a little checkbox with the label redirect checked. Some googling showed me that I needed to provide a parameter to my `GraphRequest` that disallows the redirect. Hence the correct request must be:

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
 params.putBoolean("redirect", false);

     new GraphRequest(
     AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
     "me/picture",
     params,
     HttpMethod.GET,
     new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            try {
                String picUrlString = (String) response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("data").get("url");   
                //Load picture url in imageView
                Glide.with(this).load(picUrlString).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(profilePictureView);
            } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
 ).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                String imageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + mFbUserId +"/picture?width=150&width=150";
                URL imageURI = new URL(imageURL);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURI.openConnection().getInputStream());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }.execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Facebook API Graph Version 3.2**

I've made this implementation:

First make shure you have this permissions added in "onStart" or "onCreate"
(This avoids the NetworkOnMainThreadException).

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

After that you can use the next function:

```
//Next lines are Strings used as params
public static String FACEBOOK_FIELD_PROFILE_IMAGE = "picture.type(large)";
public static String FACEBOOK_FIELDS = "fields";

//A function that can be accessed from OnCreate (Or a similar function)
private void setImageProfileFacebook(){

        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();            

        if(isLoggedIn) {
        //If the user is LoggedIn then continue
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString(Util.FACEBOOK_FIELDS, Util.FACEBOOK_FIELD_PROFILE_IMAGE);
            /* make the API call */
            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "me",
                    parameters,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            /* handle the result */
                            if (response != null) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                                    //Log.w(TAG, "Data: " + response.toString());

                                    if (data.has("picture")) {
                                        boolean is_silhouette = data.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getBoolean("is_silhouette");
                                        if (!is_silhouette) {
                                        //Silhouette is used when the FB user has no upload any profile image
                                            URL profilePicUrl = new URL(data.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url"));
                                            InputStream in = (InputStream) profilePicUrl.getContent();
                                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                                            imageViewProfileFisio.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                        }
                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Response null");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();
        }
    }
```

My example was created using the official documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile-picture-source/?locale=es_LA

Answer (score 2):

```
imgUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + user_id + "/picture?type=large";
```

then  `Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imgUrl).into(imageView);`

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is in the

```
imageURL = "**http**://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=large";
```

Use `https` insted of `http`

Answer (score 2):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString ("fields", "full_picture,message");

new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "{page-id}/feed",
                bundle,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
                        Log.e("TAG", response.toString());
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

With [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

```
userId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
```

then;

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId+ "/picture?type=large")
        .into(imgProfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it. but be sure to access setfollowredirects statically i.e  HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(HttpURLConnection.getFollowRedirects());

```
url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/ID/picture?type=small");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                                           HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(HttpURLConnection.getFollowRedirects());
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
input = connection.getInputStream();

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 300, 300);

 // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
myBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
```

or

```
url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/ID/picture?type=small");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                                                HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(HttpURLConnection.getFollowRedirects());
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
input = connection.getInputStream();
myBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I have done this way:

Get **Bitmap** from **Image Url** of **Facebook**:

```
String imageUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/103407310026838/picture?type=large&width=1000&height=1000";

Bitmap bitmap = getFacebookProfilePicture(imageUrl);
```

**Function** for **Bitmap**:

```
private Bitmap getFacebookProfilePicture(String url){
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(url));
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse mResponse;
    try {
    mResponse = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
    HttpEntity entity = mResponse.getEntity();
        BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
        httpRequest.abort();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return bitmap;
 }
```

It's Done.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void importFbProfilePhoto() {

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response) {

                        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {

                            if (me != null) {

                                String profileImageUrl = ImageRequest.getProfilePictureUri(me.optString("id"), 500, 500).toString();
                                Log.i(LOG_TAG, profileImageUrl);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        GraphRequest.executeBatchAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ImageRequest` would be great to use but it is a part of `com.facebook.internal`. The documentation on this class warns that use of these classes is unsupported. Tread at your own risk!

Answer (score 1):

```
imgUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + user_id + "/picture?type=large";
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

When you make request like this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/103407310026838/picture?type=square&type=large
```

it makes a redirect to other url..

You need to add an extra param on Get request

```
redirect=false
```

Like this

```
http://graph.facebook.com/103407310026838/picture?type=square&type=large&redirect=false
```

and you will get the a Json with Real Image url..

Like this :

```
{
   "data": {
      "is_silhouette": true,
      "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/1379841_10150004552801901_469209496895221757_n.jpg?oh=4234dcdfc832a58b9ef7a31c7896c73c&oe=57DD01F8"
   }
}
```

finally make new request to get the image that you found in data->url

Answer (score 0):

Url seems OK.

So problem is with your connection. Does URL.getContent() really return stream? Because if BitmapFactory gets null it also returns null.

Try this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
URL url = new URL(http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=large);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
}
finally {
      urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably you are run your methods in main thread
use

```
if( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9 )
{
  try
  {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( policy );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static Bitmap getFacebookProfilePicture(String userID)
                throws SocketException, SocketTimeoutException,
                MalformedURLException, IOException, Exception {
            String imageURL;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + userID
                    + "/picture?type=large";

             URL url1 = new URL(imageURL);
                HttpURLConnection ucon1 = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
                ucon1.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                URL secondURL1 = new URL(ucon1.getHeaderField("Location"));
            InputStream in = (InputStream) new URL(imageURL).getContent();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            return bitmap;
        }
```

use this code.....

Comment: **Why** should we use this code? How does it work? Code-only answers are liable to be deleted because they don't help others to understand **how** to solve a problem, and instead just solve it for them,

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null because the call to URL.openConnection() (or any other mechanism to fetch the image) is asynchronous. It returns after your line: `return bitmap;`. Therefore bitmap is always null.

I suggest using a callback instead.

This is what i did:

```
final AQuery androidQuery = new AQuery(this);

        AjaxCallback<byte[]> imageCallback = new AjaxCallback<byte[]>() {

            @Override
            public void callback(String url, byte[] avatar, AjaxStatus status) {

                if (avatar != null) {
                    save(avatar);
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Cannot fetch third party image. AjaxStatus: " + status.getError());
                }
            }

        };

        androidQuery.ajax(imageUrl, byte[].class, imageCallback);
```

Android query allows you to get the image in different formats (e.g. byte array, Bitmap, etc.). There are other libraries out there, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

A complete solution which worked for me!

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView;
import com.facebook.share.model.ShareLinkContent;
import com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    Button share,details;
    ShareDialog shareDialog;
    LoginButton login;
    ProfilePictureView profile;
    Dialog details_dialog;
    TextView details_txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        login = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        profile = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
        details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.details);
        login.setReadPermissions("public_profile email");
        share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        details_dialog = new Dialog(this);
        details_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_details);
        details_dialog.setTitle("Details");
        details_txt = (TextView)details_dialog.findViewById(R.id.details);
        details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                details_dialog.show();
            }
        });

        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
            RequestData();
            share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                    share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    profile.setProfileId(null);
                }
            }
        });
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().build();
                shareDialog.show(content);

            }
        });
        login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
                    RequestData();
                    share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            }
        });

    }
    public void RequestData(){
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

                JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                try {
                    if(json != null){
                        String text = "<b>Name :</b> "+json.getString("name")+"<br><br><b>Email :</b> "+json.getString("email")+"<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> "+json.getString("link");
                        details_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                        profile.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I search all modes to make this on API 15 only this method work for me whith Volley:

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+ fid +"/picture?type=square";
                ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url,
                        new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            }
                        }, 0, 0, null,
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

On my graph api was not working because of the question mark

If you are using 1 pram after picture it would be

```
picture&type=large
```

for two params we would use the question mark

```
picture?type=large&redirect=false
```

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score -1):

I used this code and i got the profile picture,

```
fbUsrPicURL = "http://graph.facebook.com" + File.separator
                    + String.valueOf(fbUID) + File.separator + "picture?type=large";
```

Answer (score -1):

Download the source code from [here](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/04/07/get-location-of-facebook-user-using-graph-api-in-android/)

Add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"

            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
        android:text="Email"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_email"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="DOB"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
            android:text="DOB"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_dob"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_email"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Location"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
            android:text="location"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_location"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#6585C8"
        android:id="@+id/ll_facebook"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook"
            android:id="@+id/iv_facebook"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login with Facebook"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/tv_facebook"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package facebooklocation.facebooklocation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ImageView iv_image, iv_facebook;
    TextView tv_name, tv_email, tv_dob, tv_location, tv_facebook;
    LinearLayout ll_facebook;
    String str_facebookname, str_facebookemail, str_facebookid, str_birthday, str_location;
    boolean boolean_login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        getKeyHash();
        listener();
    }


    private void init() {
        iv_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
        iv_facebook = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_facebook);
        tv_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_dob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dob);
        tv_location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        tv_facebook = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_facebook);
        ll_facebook = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_facebook);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    }

    private void listener() {
        tv_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);
        ll_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);
        iv_facebook.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void facebookLogin() {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.e("ONSUCCESS", "User ID: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                        + "\n" + "Auth Token: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                try {

                                    boolean_login = true;
                                    tv_facebook.setText("Logout from Facebook");

                                    Log.e("object", object.toString());
                                    str_facebookname = object.getString("name");

                                    try {
                                        str_facebookemail = object.getString("email");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_facebookemail = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    try {
                                        str_facebookid = object.getString("id");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_facebookid = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();

                                    }


                                    try {
                                        str_birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_birthday = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonobject_location = object.getJSONObject("location");
                                        str_location = jsonobject_location.getString("name");

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        str_location = "";
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    fn_profilepic();

                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                }
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email,gender,birthday,location");

                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
                    return; // already logged out
                }
                new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
                        .Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email"));
                        facebookLogin();

                    }
                }).executeAsync();


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.e("ON ERROR", "Login attempt failed.");


                AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    private void getKeyHash() {
        // Add code to print out the key hash
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("facebooklocation.facebooklocation", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
    }

    private void fn_profilepic() {

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putBoolean("redirect", false);
        params.putString("type", "large");
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "me/picture",
                params,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                        Log.e("Response 2", response + "");

                        try {
                            String str_facebookimage = (String) response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("data").get("url");
                            Log.e("Picture", str_facebookimage);

                            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(str_facebookimage).skipMemoryCache(true).into(iv_image);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        tv_name.setText(str_facebookname);
                        tv_email.setText(str_facebookemail);
                        tv_dob.setText(str_birthday);
                        tv_location.setText(str_location);

                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (boolean_login) {
            boolean_login = false;
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            tv_location.setText("");
            tv_dob.setText("");
            tv_email.setText("");
            tv_name.setText("");
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.profile).into(iv_image);
            tv_facebook.setText("Login with Facebook");
        } else {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_location"));
            facebookLogin();
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how your code answers the question?