# Android circular Imageview in App Widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-appwidget

So I'm trying to make an app widget and display a profile picture there which should look like a circular `ImageView`. **normally I'd just use a circular `ImageView` library, but for app widgets you can't extend views (so only vanilla `ImageView`) and it has to work with `RemoteViews`**

So I'm playing around with the idea of using a `Drawable` to overlay/underlay to achieve this effect. I tried gusridd's solution from here [Display FB profile pic in circular image view in Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464707/display-fb-profile-pic-in-circular-image-view-in-application), but the background which my profile picture sits on is also an image, and this just makes it a white square with a circlular image inside :(

edit: please read bolded portion before answering :X

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same issue in Custom Notification using RemoteView then following solution helps me out.

**Solution: Use circular cropped bitmap**

```
public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) throws Exception {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! worked almost clear for all kinds of OS