# How to create circular facebook profile picture

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap, imageview, profile-picture

I'm having trouble using this library to make one of my images into a circle dynamically. Here is my attempt:

```
private void drawerSetup() {
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    ProfilePictureView profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    CircularImageView circularProfilePicture = (CircularImageView)    findViewById(R.id.profile_image_circle);
    if(profilePictureView != null) {
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());
        ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)profilePictureView.getChildAt(0));
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        circularProfilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    app:showIn="@layout/activity_news_feed">

<com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    facebook:com_facebook_preset_size="normal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
    app:border_width="2dp"
    app:shadow="true"
    app:shadow_radius="10"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image_circle"
    app:shadow_color="#000000"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/profile_image" />
```

I know that my `profilePictureView` is displaying correctly when i call `profilePictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());` On my layout, it displays correctly. However, when I try to call the circularProfilePicture, I simply get an "empty" photo. It doesn't seem like the bitmap for the image isn't being recognized/set correctly. The image doesn't display as the `profilePictureView` does. Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: which lib you used ? Always put much information as possible. Also, did you look into logcat ? is there any exception raising ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464707/display-fb-profile-pic-in-circular-image-view-in-application

Comment: Its look like it is waiting for Image response. try to get image after a delay.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain there was no exception (not that I am aware of) and I was using https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView library. How would I set such a delay?

Comment: Whenever you use `profilePictureView` to the users picture, it actually sends an Async HTTP request to get the data, on the next line you are getting the bitmap set by the `profilePictureView` which was set empty by default. That's why you are not getting image in your `CircularView`. Library is working as expected, I tried myself.

Comment: In order to introduce a little delay before getting the image in `CircularView` use either the `Handler` `postDelayed` method or [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask, long, long)) In order to introduce a little delay before getting the image in `CircularView` use either the `Handler` `postDelayed` method or `Timer` class for introducing delay class for introducing delay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After using different image library (including Picasso), I finished to use Facebook one named [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco). It's much faster with less code, everyting works as it should.

Fresco support:

- streaming of progressive JPEGs
- display of animated GIFs and WebPs
- extensive customization of image loading and display

The doc says too that

> In Android 4.x and lower, Fresco puts images in a special region of Android memory. This lets your application run faster - and suffer the dreaded OutOfMemoryError much less often.

It also support rounded corner as you are searching, see [here](http://frescolib.org/docs/rounded-corners-and-circles.html#_).

**Layout example:**

```
        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/avatarImageView"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
            fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/photo_placeholder"
            fresco:roundAsCircle="true"/>
```

Note: don't forget to call `Fresco.initialize(this);` somewhere (normally in your Application class).

I should also notice that Fresco currently add **2.6Mb** to your application using ProGuard. You may choose to use another library such as Glide if you want less functionality.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. I just have one question: the image takes a while to actually display due to network latency. Is there any way I can put some sort of loading screen and not display the activity the image is in until the image is finished loading? I can't seem to figure it out since I'm not sure if I have to edit the `setUri` function itself or if I can put the loading screen code somewhere in the activity.

Comment: Secondly, I noticed if I set the layout_width and height to be larger than 50 dp, like 100 dp each, my picture is blurry. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: the picture will be blurry because of the size of the image. Image are in px, like 50x50px. If you want to displayed it with large size, you will see more pixels. 
About improving the image loading, you can either listen for the http://frescolib.org/docs/listening-download-events.html and display what you want at the end. To do this, ou will need to configure the Fresco cache and use an image pipeline see http://frescolib.org/docs/configure-image-pipeline.html

Comment: see sample for Fresco initialize with configuration https://gist.github.com/HugoGresse/b196f6156d7d6e84d710

Comment: Ah thank you for all your help. This works perfectly. Thanks! Just last question regarding the blurriness: is there any part of the API that actually allows me to scale or to make the image larger without having it seem so blurry? Right now I want my layout width/height to be 100 dp but my image is extremely blurry. I've been looking at this: http://frescolib.org/docs/scaling.html#_ but it seems like it just talks about focusing the image.

Comment: I've found this http://frescolib.org/docs/resizing-rotating.html#_ but cannot you use a bigger input? You are using some api to get user informations. If so, it's possible that the api (facebook does) have different image size. In this case, use a bigger one. You won't have the effect you want anyway if the image is too small

Answer (score 4):

I can't help but notice most answers asking you to use 2 libraries, 1 for loading the Image and 2nd for displaying it. Your goal as a developer should always be to get your task done with the minimum number of libraries and here is a solution that only needs 1 library. I will use Glide here since it caches the images exactly for the size you need. I haven't used Fresco so cannot comment on it but [HERE's](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) something on Picasso vs. Glide

**Step 1**

Create your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_profile"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_picture_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_picture_size"
        android:background="@drawable/image_circle"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@string/placeholder_name"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary" />
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what my Layout looks like, notice I used a plain simple ImageView instead of a fancy library. Feel free to adjust it to match your needs.

[image: Navigation Drawer header]

**Step 2**

Write a custom transform to convert a square image into a Circle Image. Glide uses something called Transformations to let you manipulate images according to what you need. Read [THIS](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Transformations) post for what transformations are and read [THIS](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations) post to play with some custom transformations. In our case our transformation class looks like this.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.Transformation;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.Resource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.BitmapPool;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapResource;

public class CropCircleTransform implements Transformation<Bitmap> {

private BitmapPool mBitmapPool;

public CropCircleTransform(Context context) {
    this(Glide.get(context).getBitmapPool());
}

public CropCircleTransform(BitmapPool pool) {
    this.mBitmapPool = pool;
}

@Override
public Resource<Bitmap> transform(Resource<Bitmap> resource, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
    Bitmap source = resource.get();
    int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

    int width = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
    int height = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

    Bitmap bitmap = mBitmapPool.get(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    if (bitmap == null) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    BitmapShader shader =
            new BitmapShader(source, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    if (width != 0 || height != 0) {
        // source isn't square, move viewport to center
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setTranslate(-width, -height);
        shader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
    }
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    float r = size / 2f;
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

    return BitmapResource.obtain(bitmap, mBitmapPool);
}

@Override public String getId() {
    return "CropCircleTransform()";
}
}
```

**Step 3**
Load the picture into this layout using Glide. Admin is an object that contains details such as name, email, profile picture url etc, mDrawer is a reference to the NavigationView. Notice how Glide uses the transformation defined in step 2 to achieve the circular image effect.

```
public void addHeaderToDrawer(@NonNull Admin admin) {
    View headerView = mDrawer.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
    TextView textUserName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.text_username);
    ImageView imageProfile = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
    textUserName.setText(admin.getName());
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(admin.getUrl())
            .asBitmap()
            .transform(new CropCircleTransform(mContext))
            .into(imageProfile);
}
```

**Step 4**

Sit back and enjoy the show. I am also loading the data from Facebook, let me know if you are still facing any issues :)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this through using `PICASSO library`.
No need to use `CircularImageView`
Here is my code:

```
Target target = new Target() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
            // Toast.makeText(FragmentChatView.this, "message",
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom arg1) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 40, 40, false);
            final Drawable drawImage = new BitmapDrawable(BaseActivity.this
                    .getBaseContext().getResources(), bitmap);
            // ((MaterialNavigationDrawer<Fragment>)
            // FragmentChatView.this).getToolbar().setLogo(drawImage);
            if (iv_logo != null)
                iv_logo.setImageDrawable(drawImage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {

        }
    };

    public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
            int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

            int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
            int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

            Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap
                    .createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
            if (squaredBitmap != source) {
                source.recycle();
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
                    BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);

            float r = size / 2f;
            canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

            squaredBitmap.recycle();
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return "circle";
        }
    }
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView. I've tried several alternatives, and this one was the lucky winner.

Comment: I just tried it and I get the same result. Do you have any example code or see anything I'm doing wrong that is having the picture not display? The "blank" photo shows (generic facebook image), but just not the actual photo.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
           <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:src="@drawable/User"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
```

shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:centerColor="#ffffff"
    android:centerX="35%"
    android:endColor="#ffffff"
    android:startColor="#ffffff"
    android:type="linear" />
<padding
    android:bottom="20dp"
    android:left="20dp"
    android:right="20dp"
    android:top="20dp" />
<size
    android:width="150dp"
    android:height="150dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="5dp"
    android:color="@color/allThemeBlue" />

</shape>
```

out put

[image]