# How can I change ProfilePictureView to circle image. Drawable is not working

Tags: facebook, drawable, android-drawable, profile-picture

I have tried to change ProfilePictureView to circle image with drawable. But it is not working.

Here is my xml for ProfilePictureView

```
     <com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profilePicture" />
```

Here is my drawable file circle.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#666666"/>

    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

Here is the function

```
        profilePictureView = view.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(userId);
        profilePictureView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23715871/5774498). They provide an edited `ProfilePictureView` class that you can use which applies a rounding effect to the image associated with the profile id.

Something that I feel was missed in the answer above is that you will need to change the namespace declaration in Java **and** in XML to point to the location of the new file.

In XML this would mean changing:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
    ...
/>
```

to:

```
<com.myapp.mypackage.view.ProfilePictureView
    ...
/>
```

After changing the import statement in Java, all you must do is provide the profile id.

```
profilePictureView = view.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
profilePictureView.setProfileId(userId);
```